# Get Distinct values out of List<Object>

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List` that contains instances of `Beam` class. Each of these `Beam` objects has an `Elevation` property.

```
List<Beam> Beams = new List<Beam> {Beam1, Beam2, ...};

public class Beam
{
    public double Elevation;
}
```

Now I want to create a `List<double>` that contains distinct Elevations.
For example how to write a method that accepts the Beams list as below

```
var Beam1 = new Beam { Elevation = 320);
var Beam2 = new Beam { Elevation = 320);
var Beam3 = new Beam { Elevation = 640);
var Beam4 = new Beam { Elevation = 0);

List<Beam> Beams = new List<Beam> {Beam1, Beam2, Beam3, Beam4};
```

And gives this removing the duplicate elevations:

```
listOfElevations = {0, 320,640}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make Beam implement IComparable:

```
public class Beam : IComparable
{
    public double Elevation; //consider changing this to property, btw.

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
         if (obj == null) return 1;

         Beam otherBeam = obj as Beam;
         return this.Elevation.CompareTo(otherBeam.Elevation);
    }
}
```

2) use Distinct():

```
var listOfElevations = Beams.Distinct().Select(x=> x.Elevation).ToList();
```

Comment: The first method seems quite interesting and powerful. I will definitely look into it. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use both of the methods, in first you just define, when two `Beam` objects are the same, in the second one you just get distinct Beans.

Comment: Oh now I see. So this way I'm actually able to inject my own logic into comparing the two objects and define how they are considered equal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq - in particular the [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is key here:

```
var listOfElevations  = beams.Select(x => x.Elevation) //project to Elevations
                             .Distinct() // pick only distinct ones
                             .ToList(); //make it a list
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed to do it on one call.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple using LinQ:

```
var listOfElevations = Beams.Select(x => x.Elevation).Distinct().ToList();
```

You're selecting the values of Elevation, choosing the Distinct values, making it to a List since it's your expected output.

Comment: Thanks Saverio for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Beam> Beams = new List<Beam> {Beam1, Beam2, Beam3, Beam4};
        var differentBeams = Beams.Select(b => b.Elevation).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `LINQ`, this might be useful if you have more than one property and want to get an unique list

```
beams.GroupBy(x => x.Elevation).Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks. The `Key` is the second property here?

Comment: @Vahid no the key is the key of your group, so it's `Elevation`.If you want to get an unique list of object instead of selecting key you need to select first element from each group using `g.First()`

Comment: How can I implement this to get unique objects when I have say two properties? Say `Elevation` and `Section` as you said?

Comment: `beams.GroupBy(x => x.Elevation).Select(g => g.First());`

Comment: What about the `Section` then? The second property?

Comment: You mean it groups the Beams by Elevation first then chooses the ones that have Distinct Sections?

Comment: @Vahid yes, it groups your beams based on Elevation then selects first element from each group.as a result all of your objects will have unique Elevation