# Select distinct objects from a List<Object>

Tags: c#, list

I have asked a rather similar question here.
[Get Distinct values out of List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896232/get-distinct-values-out-of-listobject)

But this question is not duplicate. It is similar as I have stated but far from duplicate. In the other question, we are getting the Values using Distinct, here we are getting Objects.

But I'm having problems to get this right.

I have the `List<Beam>` defined as below:

```
List<Beam> Beams = new List<Beam>;

public class
{
    public double Elevation;
}
```

How can I get the distinct objects from a `List<Beam>` based on `Elevation` property?

Comment: Please clarify [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896232/get-distinct-values-out-of-listobject) instead of asking the same question again with less information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GroupBy here:

```
var distinctBeams = beams
    .GroupBy(b => b.Elevation)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. This worked perfectly. Can I order them by Elevation too?

Comment: @Vahid `.OrderBy(b => b.Elevation)` after the select, or before the groupby.

Answer (score 1):

`using System.Linq;`

```
public class Beam
{
        public double Elevation;

        protected bool Equals(Beam other)
        {
            return Elevation.Equals(other.Elevation);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Beam) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Elevation.GetHashCode();
        }
}
```

`var distinctBeams = beams.Distinct()`

Comment: @Vahid Added Equality members

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could simply do

```
var distinctList = beams.GroupBy(b=>b.Elevation).Select(g=>g.first());
```

Basically group the object by whatever property you want and take one of each.