# Implement IEquatable Get distinct objects

Tags: vb.net, distinct-values

This is not working for me. I couldn't find the answer on MSDN or elsewhere after having spent too much time on it. What am I missing?

```
Public Class PrinterInfo
    Implements IEquatable(Of PrinterInfo)
    Public PrinterName As String
    Public PrinterDesc As String

    'default equality comparer for class vb.net
    Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal other As PrinterInfo) As Boolean _
       Implements IEquatable(Of PrinterInfo).Equals
        Return other.PrinterName = Me.PrinterName
    End Function

End Class

Public ReadOnly Property PrinterInfoList(ByVal Normal As NormalCopier) As List(Of PrinterInfo)
    Get
        Dim pList1 As List(Of PrinterInfo) = GetList
        pList1.Sort()
        Return pList1.Distinct.ToList
    End Get
End Property
```

I get the list just fine but I want only distinct items. I tried to implement an equality comparer but it's not working. I'm getting multiple duplicates. What do I need to do to get only distinct values?

[MSDN: Enumerable.Distinct(Of TSource)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[MSDN: IEqualityComparer(Of T) Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[This seems similar but I don't understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896232/get-distinct-values-out-of-listobject)

I'd like to avoid Linq GroupBy if I can. That just seems clumsy to me.

Comment: consider `KeyedCollection` [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [Enumerable.Distinct(Of Source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The default equality comparer, `Default`, is used to compare values of the types that implement the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface ***and provide your own `GetHashCode`*** and `Equals` methods for the type.

That's the part you're missing.  You are expected to provide a `GetHashCode()` implementation in your class. If you look at the code examples given, you'll see it there too.  And when you think about it, it makes sense.  The implementation of `Distinct` uses a hash set internally, so it naturally requires a proper `GetHashCode` implementation to function properly.

In your case, try adding this to your `PrinterInfo` class:

```
Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Return Me.PrinterName.GetHashCode()
End Function
```

Comment: That made all the difference. Sort also isn't working but that's not as important. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: to get the sorting to work, you'll need to also implement the [IComparable(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.